# Trying to write a Java program to encrypt and decrypt a ADFGVX cypher, finding it confusing

Tags: java, for-loop, encryption, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt a message using a Polybius Square, I know how this works on paper but dont know where to start when turing it into a program. I was planning to use a hashmap but I was told thats a bad way to go about it and that theres better approuchs to do this that are easier... like what?
I've been given code to help me by my lecture from a workshop on the project but I dont fully understand it. I'll paste it below and if anyone could explain it I would greatly appreciate it! I've been focusing on C alot this past while so now im a bit rusty when it comes to Java.

Here a double array I've made myself for the polybius grid, how do I incorperate ADFGVX into this?

```
char [][] poly = new char[][]{
            {'p','h','0','q','g','6'},
            {'4','m','e','a','1','y'},
            {'l','2','n','o','f','d'},
            {'x','k','r','3','c','v'},
            {'s','5','z','w','7','b'},
            {'j','9','u','t','i','8'}};
```

Thats a double array that I'll be using to stort the Polybius square right?

```
for(int row = 0; row<poly.length,row++){}
for(int col = 0; col<poly[row].length,col++){}
if(poly[row][col] = MyChar That Im Looking For){
}
```

This is used for navigating the array and finding the chars I want?

```
// how to break a line down to a character
   String[] words = line.split(" ");
   for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++){
      String word = words[i];
      for(int j = 0; j <word.length(); j++){
        char letter = word.charAt(j);
        encrypt(letter);
    }
 }
```

This is breaking a line down to letters ovbiously? what do I do then? also is the method encrypt in the java lib or do I have to make my own somehow?
I'm not sure where to begin or what would be the best way to go about this, I think I might just watch hash map tutorials and try that? This is my first time trying encryption and the whole thing looks hard and intimidating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a Java program to encrypt and decrypt a ADFGVX cipher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319831/writing-a-java-program-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-adfgvx-cipher)

Comment: Don't post new questions just because your first question wasn't answered. You can edit your previous question to include new insights.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is this just an exercise to learn java and/or play around with cyphers, or do you want to use it in real-life? In case of th e latter, consider using one of the built-in cryptography methods.

Comment: I need to write a program that will decrypt and encrypt the cypher, thats it. Any pointers or advice on where to start would be great because, I know how the cypher works I just have no idea how to turn it into code!